# Trying to call SSDP functions from Cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova-plugins, ssdp

I am trying to test SSDP implementation the exists in the following Cordova plugin:
https://github.com/fraunhoferfokus/cordova-plugin-hbbtv/tree/master/src/android/ssdp

I have built an SSDP service on my laptop using Node.js which I successfully discovered on another laptop. Now I need to discover that service on my Android mobile and I "have to" use this Cordova plugin because  I need to test it but its documentation only about Hbbtv, so I am not sure how to call its SSDP functions in my Cordova js Webview do I need to add something to the JavaScript API file.

Can someone show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone was facing the same problem I was, here is what I did to solve it.

Basically, I called `DiscoveredTerminal()` from `HbbTV.js` and it gave me the number of discovered devices.